# Execute stored procedure SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am trying to execute the created stored procedure from inside the stored procedure. How can I do it ?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.ListAllPersonnel
Go

CREATE PROCEDURE ListAllPersonnel
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM personnel

    EXECUTE dbo.ListAllPersonnel
GO
```

Comment: Your procedure has an infinite loop in it. What happens when you run it?

Comment: And what do you intend to achieve with running this procedure infinitely? What's the point of creating and running a procedure in one go??